# Laravel 5.4 - reading csv file

Tags: php, csv, laravel-5.4

I am uploading a csv file in `public/uploads` folder. And then I am trying to read it. This is how I try to do it:

```
$path = base_path('uploads/' .$file->getClientOriginalName());
$data = fopen($path, 'r');
```

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How can I open and read the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base_path` function returns the fully qualified path to the project root. So you have to add `public/` to your parameter.

```
$path = base_path('public/uploads/' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
```